# Filtering in Controller not resolving the belongsTo relationship whereas template does

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The full list of inspections is provided by the Route and stored in fixtures. I'm trying to extract the current inspections from the full inspection list using a computed property with a filter from within the controller...

When I display the elements from the model in the template and access the *item.status.code*, it is resolved properly.

When I try to filter on that property from the controller, it seems it is not available (loaded:= false - see the logs in the browser console when running the [JSBin Demo of the problem](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yehom/5/watch?js,output)).

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  currentInspections: function() {
  var mod = this.get('model');
  Ember.Logger.log('Model: ', mod);
  return mod.filter(function(item, index, enumerable) {
    Ember.Logger.log("Inspection:            ", item);
    Ember.Logger.log("status --> isLoaded:   ", item.get('status').get('isLoaded'));
    Ember.Logger.log("status --> unique get: ", item.get('status.code'));
    Ember.Logger.log("status --> 2 get:      ", item.get('status').get('code'));

    return item.get('status.code') === "inProgress";
  }); 
}.property("model.@each")
```

Yields the following:

```
Model:  
Class {type: function, store: Class, isLoaded: true, isUpdating: false, toString: function…}
Inspection:             
Class {id: "1", store: Class, container: Container, _changesToSync: Object, _deferredTriggers: Array[0]…}
status --> isLoaded:    false
status --> unique get:  undefined
status --> 2 get:       undefined
...
```

Either I'm missing the way it is supposed to be done or there might be a bug in ember-data or emberjs itself that makes the object not loaded at this stage in the event processing chain...

I've been fiddling with this for a while now and I'm going round and round in circles not finding the solution...

Could someone inspired have a look at it, I really need an external view on this problem.

Is there a way to force the load of the status object?

Should I be doing this filtering somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been facing the same problems some weeks ago. And it's actually quiet easy to fix.

The first problem that I see here is that you did not define wether the relashions are async or not. Make sure to define it (at least for us because the procedure will be different). I advice you to consult this [link](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-data-relationships-like-polymorphic-async-inverse-embedded/5029/3) which is really helpful.

The second problem (in the case of async data) is that the status object is not yet resolved when you tried to get it's code property which explains the `undefined`. Ember define three methods that are launched while resolving the route. First `beforeModel`, then `model` and finally `afterModel`. You can use the last route to make an iteration over your model and store all `status` promise in an array and make the method to return `Ember.RSVP.Promise.all(array)`;

Example:

```
afterModel: function(model) {
    return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all(model.map(function(item) {
        return item.get('status');
    }));
}
```

In the case of non async data, I actually don't know because I'm not using that type of fetching.